# Grails Spring Security: move to another page when account is expired

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-controller

I have implemented a web site with Grails 3.x and spring security 3.1.
I can manage user registration and authentication in my login page. 
I'd like to manage the expiration account as well. If I have an account expired, login page says that you cannot proceed due to account expired, when you try to login, which is fine. But instead of having the error message in the login page, I'd like to intercept it and show another completely different page, but I have no idea how to do it.

thanks

**UPDATE**

RTFM:

You can configure exception mappings in **application.groovy** to associate a URL to any or all of these exceptions to determine where to redirect after a failure, for example.

Example grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.exceptionMappings configuration

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException

grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.exceptionMappings = [
   [exception: LockedException.name,             url: '/user/accountLocked'],
   [exception: DisabledException.name,           url: '/user/accountDisabled'],
   [exception: AccountExpiredException.name,     url: '/user/accountExpired'],
   [exception: CredentialsExpiredException.name, url: '/user/passwordExpired']
]
```

Comment: Consider posting your update as an answer.

Comment: You can refer latest grails spring security document as well for the same.